# Constraint on non-id in foreign table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

```
EMAIL_QUEUE
  ID identity,
  MIME_TYPE_ID int foreign key MIME_TYPE(id)
  etc...

MIME_TYPE
  ID identity,
  MIME_TYPE varchar(300),
  etc...
```

MIME_TYPEs are not currently declared unique. I want a constraint on my EMAIL_QUEUE table so that it only accepts certain mime types (text/plain and text/html). What is the best practice for doing this?

1. Use a custom function and a check constraint
2. Make the MIME_TYPE column the primary key of the MIME_TYPE table and put a constraint on the possible values
3. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check constraint. For example, if the IDs of the two desired mime types are 3 and 4:

```
ALTER TABLE EMAIL_QUEUE WITH CHECK
  ADD CONSTRAINT MIME_TYPE_CHECK CHECK (MIME_TYPE_ID IN (3,4))
```

ID values are not supposed to change, so it's OK to hard code the values that are acceptable.

Comment: Okay, but then what happens if the ID is different in different environments? I'd have to write a different script for each environment. Unfortunately, I can't promise that the ID for text/plain will be the same in each environment (dev, qa, staging, prod)

Comment: Check constraints can't look up other tables. It is good practice to use source-controlled scripts to populate "look up" tables with hard-coded (not auto incremented) keys/values so the kind of problem you describe doesn't exist, and this kind of solution will work for you. The contents of the table should be released with every code release. Google "liquibase" for one good example of a tool that may be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

This also can be resolved with one additional table

```
-- this table is unchanged
MIME_TYPE
  ID identity,
  MIME_TYPE varchar(300),
  etc...

-- additional table, which should contain ids of the 'text/plain' and 'text/html'
EMAIL_QUEUE_MIME_TYPE
  ID int -- PK and FK to MIME_TYPE(id)

-- in this table MIME_TYPE_ID should be redirected to new table
EMAIL_QUEUE
  ID identity,
  MIME_TYPE_ID int foreign key EMAIL_QUEUE_MIME_TYPE(id)
  etc...
```